# C# Control what an external DLL can access?

Tags: c#, .net, security, dll, .net-assembly

I'm building a project that will support loading in external, managed DLLs, essentially as a modding system. However due to security reasons I'd like to restrict (as far as possible) what those external DLLs can access and do because they won't be made by myself.

My current plan was to simply blanket ban every assembly besides a select whitelist which I can add to upon request, however my main issue is the System.dll. It's probably the most important one to restrict access to due to the obvious reason that it can access System, however it also has vital namespaces like System.Collections, so it needs to be useable.

Is there a way to check specifically what assemblies and namespaces a loaded DLL is utilising or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way. You should sandbox the DLL. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691363/c-sharp-load-sandboxed-assembly) and its linked questions as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be exactly what I need :)