# Math (in WPF): Getting new x,y coordinates after a translation

Tags: wpf, math, matrix, translation, angle

*With reference to [this programming game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505040/developing-a-robocode-type-game-with-net-for-a-school-assignment) I am currently building.*

I am using WPF to animate canvases, and I am using the `BeginAnimation` method to translate (move) a canvas across another canvas.

With the BeginAnimation, I need to specify the `From` and `To` coordinates for both x and y, and this is the method I am using this like such:

```
//X 
Animator_Body_X.From = Translate_Body.X; //Current x-coordinate
Animator_Body_X.To = //The end X-coordinate
Translate_Body.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, Animator_Body_X);

//Y
Animator_Body_Y.From = Translate_Body.Y; //Current y-coordinate
Animator_Body_Y.To = //The end Y-coordinate
Translate_Body.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, Animator_Body_Y);
```

Now the canvas needs to be translated using a given angle, which I have available from the method.

So my question is, **given the angle (0-359) the canvas is currently rotated at, starting x and y coordinates (of where the canvas is currently situated) and distance (in px), how do I calculate to end coordinates?** ie to where the canvas will finally be translated to.

[alt text http://img244.imageshack.us/img244/4794/canvastranspositionmi5.jpg](http://img244.imageshack.us/img244/4794/canvastranspositionmi5.jpg)

In the above image, I have drawn an example of what I want to achieve.

Suppose the canvas (solid-border box) has a current heading (angle) of 130 degrees, and it needs to be translated (following a path down that angle; ie depending on where it is currently facing) by 200 pixels...what will be the new coordinates (where it will stop animating: dashed-border box) of the canvas? How do I calculate these new coordinates of where it will stop?

**[UPDATE] Solution:**

Thanks to the help of both [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534424/math-in-wpf-getting-new-x-y-coordinates-after-a-translation/534475#534475) and [Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534424/math-in-wpf-getting-new-x-y-coordinates-after-a-translation/534628#534628), it is finally working as intended.

And here is the working code:

```
double headingRadians = Heading * (Math.PI / 180);

Animator_Body_X.From = Translate_Body.X;
Animator_Body_X.To = Math.Sin(headingRadians) * pix + Translate_Body.X;
Translate_Body.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, Animator_Body_X);

Animator_Body_Y.From = Translate_Body.Y;
Animator_Body_Y.To = ((Math.Cos(headingRadians) * pix) * -1) + Translate_Body.Y;
Translate_Body.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, Animator_Body_Y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're rotating clockwise from 12 o'clock, your new x-coordinate will be:

```
sin(130) * 200 = 153 + original x-coordinate
```

And your new y-coordinate will be

```
cos(130) * 200 = -129 + original y-coordinate (assuming negative 'y' is down)
```

As below, note that in C#, for example, `sin` and `cos` take radians, not degrees - multiply by `Math.PI/180` to get the value in radians first.

Comment: It is almost working, with your equations.
But it is moving backwards, instead of forward.  What should I change in the equation ?

Comment: Yes - the starting points.

If your 'y' coordinates get larger as you move down the page, you may have to multiply the result of cos(130)*200 by -1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cos` and `sin` to work out the amount of movement in the x and y coordinates. This is based on the [unit circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).

The unit circle has angles starting from the right side, going anti-clockwise. So in the unit circle your angle of 130 degrees is actually 320 degrees.

```
actualAngle = 90 - 130 = -40 
(which is the same as 320 degrees when used in sin/cos)
```

The other thing to note is that the `cos` and `sin` functions are using [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) instead of degrees.

```
angleInRadians = 320 * pi / 180 (about 5.59)
x = cos(angleInRadians) * 200 + 300 (about 453.21)
y = sin(angleInRadians) * 200 + 400 (about 271.44)
```

Comment: It's almost working, but the y coordinate is going up, instead of down.  What should I change from the equation?

Comment: Also, how do I derive the proper Unit Circle angle ?  like you derived 320 from 130.  as in, what formula should I use ?

Answer (score 1):

I will detail how you can do without using Mathematics :

Note that, I don't try what I'm saying, so maybe there is some mistakes.

I will call the square you are moving Visual B,

I will call the container of the square Visual A.

Now, you want to be able to do a translation of B from B origin to B', and retrieve B' coordinate from A origin.

If your translation is (200,0), then the coordinate of B' from B origin is (200,0).
You want these coordinates from A origin. So you have to do.

```
var transform = B.TransformToVisual(A);
var pointFromAOrigin  = transform.Transform(new Point(200,0));
```

pointFromAOrigin reflect what you want.

Answer (score 0):

look at the [TransformToVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.transformtovisual.aspx) if you have the coordinate of your object from Visual A origin and you want the coordinates of your object from Visual B origin, then you do

```
   var transformation = A.TransformToVisual(B);
```

you can cast transformation from GeneralTransform to Transform if needed.
Then you can use Transform method of your GeneralTransform object.

Comment: But in this case, B doesn't exist because the canvas is not moving to another object.
  But thanks for the mention of TransformToVisual; didn't know about it, and I will use it for something else.

Comment: In this case B is the object that you are moving whose coordinates are (300,400) in the canvas.

Comment: Sorry, I meant B is your windows, and A the square (what you call Canvas). See my other answer.