# Calculating if an angle is between two angles

Tags: math, trigonometry

So I am making a little game where I am checking if a character can "see" another where character A can see character B if A is within a certain distance of B, and the direction in degrees of A is +/- 45 degrees of the angle B is facing.

Currently, I do a little calculation where I'm checking if

```
(facingAngle - 45) =< angleOfTarget =< (facingAngle + 45)
```

This works fine except for when we cross the 360 degree line.

Let's say `facingAngle = 359, angleOfTarget = 5`.  In this situation, the target is only 6 degrees off center, so I want my function to return true.  Unfortunately, 5 is not between 314 and 404.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if angle lies between 2 other angles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406189/determine-if-angle-lies-between-2-other-angles)

Comment: you can find solution in here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044905/simple-angle-between-two-angles-of-circle/3316065#3316065

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just try

```
anglediff = (facingAngle - angleOfTarget + 180 + 360) % 360 - 180

if (anglediff <= 45 && anglediff>=-45) ....
```

The reason is that the difference in angles is `facingAngle - angleOfTarget` although due to wrapping effects, might be off by 360 degrees.

The add 180+360 then modulo 360 then subtract 180, effectively just converts everything to the range -180 to 180 degrees (by adding or subtracting 360 degrees).

Then you can check the angle difference easily, whether it is within -45 to 45 degrees.

Comment: At first I tought it wasn't working in the topic case, but then I tested in Python.. Working!! So I went back to Pascal to figure out why it wasn't working there, turns out that `mod` in Pascal doesn't work with negative numbers...

Comment: This fails in the case where facingAngle is 0 and angleOfTarget is 359, for example.

Unless I'm missing something, you get (0 - 359 + 180) % 360 - 180 = -359.

An absolute value is required around the facingAngle - angleOfTarget subtraction.

Comment: You don't need to add 360 inside the parentheses as 360 % 360 is always 0 so the effect is always nothing.  Otherwise great solution!
That is: anglediff = (facingAngle - angleOfTarget + 180) % 360 - 180

if (anglediff <= 45 && anglediff>=-45) ....

Answer (score 17):

Here is a simple function I found online, and modified. **It works correctly for any angles (can be outside of 0-360)**. (This function is made to work in c, works in Xcode.)

Remember, it checks COUNTER-CLOCKWISE from angle A to angle B. It returns **YES** (true) if the angle is between :)

First, a simple conversion function to make all angles 1-360

```
//function to convert angle to 1-360 degrees
 static inline double angle_1to360(double angle){
 angle=((int)angle % 360) + (angle-trunc(angle)); //converts angle to range -360 + 360
 if(angle>0.0)
 return angle;
 else
 return angle + 360.0;
 }
```

Check if angle is between :)

```
//check if angle is between angles
 static inline BOOL angle_is_between_angles(float N,float a,float b) {
 N = angle_1to360(N); //normalize angles to be 1-360 degrees
 a = angle_1to360(a);
 b = angle_1to360(b);

 if (a < b)
 return a <= N && N <= b;
 return a <= N || N <= b;
 }
```

[image]

Eg. To check if the angle 300 is between 180 and 10 degrees:

```
BOOL isBetween=angle_is_between_angles( 300, 180,10);
```

//RETURNS YES

Comment: Seems to work for Java if trunc() is replaced with Math.floor().

Comment: Should be noted that you can read an `else` between `return a <= N && N <= b;` and `return a <= N || N <= b;`

Comment: How about if

(a = 10, 
b = 5,
N = 355)

Will angle_is_between_angles() return true if we use those as arguments?

Comment: @Bilal yes, it returns true for your example, which is correct result.

Comment: `angle_is_between_angles(270, 359.9, 180.1) - false`   
`angle_is_between_angles(-90, 359.9, 180.1) - false`

Answer (score 9):

There is a trigonometric solution that avoids the wrapping problem.

I'm assuming that you have (x, y) coordinates for both characters `P1` and `P2`.  You've already specified that you know the distance between the two which you presumably calculated using Pythagoras' theorem.

You can use the *dot product* of two vectors to calculate the angle between them:

```
A . B = |A| . |B| . cos(theta).
```

If you take `A` as the `facingAngle` vector it will be `[cos(fA), sin(fA)]`, and will have magnitude `|A|` of 1.

If you take `B` as the vector between the two characters, and your distance above you get:

```
cos(theta) = (cos(fA) * (P2x - P1x) + sin(fA) * (P2y - P1y)) / |B|
```

where `|B|` is the distance you've already calculated.

You don't need to actually take the inverse cosine to find `theta`, since for range of -45 to +45 you just need to check for `cos(theta) >= 0.70710678` (i.e. `1 / sqrt(2)`).

This might seem *slightly* complicated, but the chances are that you've already got all of the required variables hanging around in your program anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to handle wrapping at the low end (into negative values), is just to add 360 to all your values:

```
(facingAngle + 315) =< (angleOfTarget + 360) =< (facingAngle + 405)
```

That way, the subtraction of 45 can never go negative, because it no longer happens.

To handle wrapping at the top end, you need to check again, adding *another* 360 to the `angleOfTarget` value:

```
canSee  = (facingAngle + 315 <= angleOfTarget + 360) &&
          (angleOfTarget + 360 <= facingAngle + 405);
canSee |= (facingAngle + 315 <= angleOfTarget + 720) &&
          (angleOfTarget + 720 <= facingAngle + 405);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using always minimum positive difference and comparing with threshold:

```
anglediff = Math.min(Math.abs(facingAngle - angleOfTarget), 360 - Math.abs(angleOfTarget - allowDirection));
if (anglediff <= 45)
```

Answer (score 0):

Restating Alnitak's answer in a different way, a solution that avoids the angle wrap at 360 degrees is to restate the problem in a different coordinate system where the angles are always small. Here is the code:

```
def inside_angle(facing, target):
    dot = cos(facing)*cos(target) + sin(facing)*sin(target)
    angle = acos(dot)

    return angle <= pi/4
```

This is done using vector projection. Assuming the vectors |facing> = [cos(facing)  sin(facing)] and |target> = [cos(target) sin(target)], when projecting the target into the facing vector, the angle will range from zero, when the target is exactly at the facing vector or will increase to either side. This way we can just compare it to pi/4 (45 degrees). The formula for the angle is the following:

```
cos(angle) = <facing|target> / <target|target> <facing|facing>
```

That is, the cosine of the angle is the dot product between the vectors |facing> and |target> divided their modules, which is 1 in this case, which becomes:

```
angle = acos(<facing|target>)
```

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection