# Select angle in range

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to check which angles in a numpy array are within a given alpha +/- delta.
Some problems arise when the range is crossing 0 or 360.

If I ignore boundary cases, I could do:

```
import numpy as np
def angleInRange(X,alpha,delta):
    return  (alpha - delta <= X) & (X <= alpha + delta)
```

If I test it with `X = np.array([0, 5, 180, 355, 360])` is obtain

```
>>> print(angleInRange(X,170,30))
[False False  True False False]     # Correct
>>> print(angleInRange(X,10 ,30))
[ True  True False False False]     # 355 and 360 are not selected
>>> print(angleInRange(X,350,30))
[False False False  True  True]     # 0 and 5 are not selected
```

If I want to obtain the correct result I need to do something like

```
def angleInRange(X,alpha,delta):
    test = (   ((alpha       - delta <= X) & (X <= alpha       + delta))
             | ((alpha + 360 - delta <= X) & (X <= 360                ))
             | ((                  0 <= X) & (X <= alpha - 360 + delta))
           )

    return test
```

which yields to:

```
>>> print(angleInRange(X,170,30))
[False False  True False False]
>>> print(angleInRange(X,10 ,30))
[ True  True False True True ]
>>> print(angleInRange(X,350,30))
[True True False  True  True]
```

This is correct, but is there a more pythonic and less cumbersome way to achieve this? Could the modulo (%) operator help here?

Comment: don't use `&` use `and`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating if an angle is between two angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234574/calculating-if-an-angle-is-between-two-angles)

Comment: Regarding `|` and `&` in place of `or` and `and`: the fact is that X could be either a numpy array or a pandas series. While the firsts work for both, `or` and `and` (as well as chained comparison) doesn't work with pandas

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it's logical to use *chained comparisons* (`a < X and X < b` becomes `a < X < b`) and *logical operators* which short-circuit (`|` and  `&` test both left & right operands even if the final result is known only with left operand, use `or` and `and` instead):

```
test =   ((alpha       - delta <= X <= alpha       + delta)
         or (alpha + 360 - delta <= X <= 360                )
         or (                  0 <= X <= alpha - 360 + delta))
```

Answer (score -1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234574/calculating-if-an-angle-is-between-two-angles) or [this other one](https://www.xarg.org/2010/06/is-an-angle-between-two-other-angles/) will probably help you.

Basically this way you use the property of modulo and angles being cyclic:

```
def angleInRange(X, alpha, delta):
    anglediff = (X - alpha + 180 + 360) % 360 - 180
    return (-delta <= anglediff <= delta)
```

Comment: Ok, I'll do that next time, but to me it seems a bit as reinventing the wheel :)