# Data augmentation in Tensorflow using Estimator API and TFRecords dataset

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm using Tensorflow's 1.3 Estimator API to perform some image classification. Since I have a considerable amount of data, I gave the TFRecords a go. Saved the file and can read the examples to a Dataset using a parser function inside the input_fn of the estimator model. So far so good.

The issue is when I want to do some image augmentation (rotating and shearing in this case).

1) I tried using the `tf.contrib.keras.preprocessing.image.random_shear`and the likes. Turns out Keras doesn't like the format of TF's shape ('Dimension') and I can't cast it to a list because its arguments are the axis indexes not the actual value.

2) Then I tried using the `tf.contrib.image.rotate` and `tf.contrib.image.transform` with random values in my chosen range. This time I get an error of `NotFoundError: Op type not registered 'ImageProjectiveTransform' in binary running on MYPC. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process.` which is an open issue (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9672). At the moment I can't move from Windows, so I would very interested in possible alternatives.

3) Searched for a way to read TFRecords and transform it to numpy array and do the augmentation with other tools, but can't find a way from within the input_fn from where I can't access the session.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using function from the answer to the question below?[tensorflow: how to rotate an image for data augmentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801342/tensorflow-how-to-rotate-an-image-for-data-augmentation)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I can't use the eval inside an input function to use in Estimator because I don't have access to the session, but I took the implementation for rotation in another answer and it works. Also saw a commit in the issue I mentioned correcting the Windows op registry, so it should be solved in distributed binaries as well. Sorry I can't accept this answer yet as it still misses the general transform (or shear specific function).

Comment: No worries (about accepting the answer). I was checked myself on TF 1.3.0 and was surprised that the op is available under Linux but is not under Windows.