# tf.contrib.image.rotate() causes error - The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run

```
zzz = tf.contrib.image.rotate(image, 0.0348, interpolation='NEAREST')
```

but getting the error:

---

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         5 
>         6 
>   ----> 7 zzz = tf.contrib.image.rotate(image, 0.0348, interpolation='NEAREST')
>         8 
>         9 # zz = []
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/image/python/ops/image_ops.py
>   in rotate(images, angles, interpolation, name)
>        88         images,
>        89         angles_to_projective_transforms(angles, image_height, image_width),
>   ---> 90         interpolation=interpolation)
>        91     if image_or_images.get_shape().ndims is None:
>        92       raise TypeError("image_or_images rank must be statically known")
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/image/python/ops/image_ops.py
>   in transform(images, transforms, interpolation, output_shape, name)
>       273     if output_shape is None:
>       274       output_shape = tensor_util.constant_value(
>   --> 275           array_ops.shape(images)[1:3]) or array_ops.shape(images)[1:3]
>       276 
>       277     output_shape = ops.convert_to_tensor(
>
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

What am I missing?

**Update:**

I am using Tensorfloe 1.12.0 on google collab.
running below code gives same error

```
image = np.zeros((50, 90, 3)); tf.contrib.image.rotate(image, .3)
```

This error message comes when eager ex. is enabled with tf.enable_eager_execution()

Comment: this should be straight forward according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45663250/9499646

Comment: What is the shape and type of `image` here?

Comment: shape is (50, 90, 3), type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: @BiBi not working, just found this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23654

Comment: Which tensorflow version do you have? `image = np.zeros((50, 90, 3)); tf.contrib.image.rotate(image, .3)` works fine with tensorflow 1.8.

Comment: running on google collab - 1.12.0

Comment: Just tried the code from my previous comment on tensorflow 1.12 in google colab and it runs fine. How do you define `image`?

Comment: using "skvideo.io.vread" to convert mp4 video into an array and then taking one image, I used matplotlib.pyplot to check the array and it plots image correctly.