# Keras ImageDataGenerator with center crop for rotation and translation shift

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, crop, data-augmentation

I need to do data augmentation but not with any fill modes, `constant`, `reflect`, `nearest`, `wrap`. Instead everytime the image is rotated or translated, I would like to have it center-cropped (shown below) so as not have any black, white, reflected, or constant edges/borders as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50906665/3125070).

[image]

How do I extend the `ImageDataGenerator` class (if that's the only way to do it and no center crop is available out of the box) with these points taken into account?

1. Keep existing parts of the [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) other than the augmentation part, and write a custom augmentation function
2. It would be efficient to retain the images of original size without resizing  before augmentation happens because center crop would result in huge loss of data after resize. `Translate/Rotate -> Center crop -> Resize` should be more efficient than `Resize -> Translate/Rotate -> Center crop`

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is looking for a solution, here's how I managed to solve the problem. The main idea is to wrap the `ImageDataGenerator` in a custom generator, like this:

```
def crop_generator(batches, new_size):
    while True:
        batch_x, batch_y = next(batches)
        x= batch_x.shape[1] // 2
        y= batch_x.shape[2] // 2
        size = new_size // 2
        yield (batch_x[:, x-size:x+size, y-size:y+size], batch_y)

x_train = HDF5Matrix(...)
y_train = HDF5Matrix(...)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=180, ...)

model = create_model()

training_gen = crop_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128), new_size=64)

model.fit_generator(training_gen, ...)
```

Using numpy indexing `batch_x[:, x-size:x+size, y-size:y+size, :]` we only alter `x` and `y` dimensions of the images, leaving batch size and channel dimensions the same. This allows us to avoid the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful,

**Extending Keras' ImageDataGenerator to Support Random Cropping**

https://jkjung-avt.github.io/keras-image-cropping/

github code:

https://github.com/jkjung-avt/keras-cats-dogs-tutorial/blob/master/train_cropped.py

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(......)
train_batches = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(DATASET_PATH + '/train',
                                              target_size=(256,256),
                                              ......)
train_crops = crop_generator(train_batches, 224)
net_final.fit_generator(train_crops, ......)
```